# c# accessing string from method1 in method2, after method1's execution

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, combobox

I'm working on a form with one textbox, one button, one combobox and a couple of other textboxes.

So, I want this winforms program to work as follows:
1) you fill in a database index value in textbox1 (example: 22222)
2) you click the button. This button goes to the database, looks up the value in textbox1 and eventually creates a string based on what the database returns. (example: returned value = super; string value = 5)
3) After you've clicked the button, you should be able to fill in the other textboxes **depending on the SelectedIndex** of the combobox. The values filled in in the combobox are completely dependant on the value of the string generated by button1. (example: combobox1 selectedindex = 1: textbox2.text = S; combobox selectedIndex = 2: textbox3.text = U)

So, basically, button1 must first be executed before combobox1 can even begin to execute itself. Also note that there are (at least) two methods used here: a void for button1_click and a void for combobox1_selectedindexchanged.

The two first parts are done. What I'm having trouble with is accessing the string generated by button1, which is only accessible after its execution, and using it in combobox1's method.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

create a property on your Form class which is populated once the button 1 is clicked with the value from your textbox.

then simply use it whenever and however you need.

example code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string Value;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Value = textBox1.Text;
            textBox2.Text = this.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give a theoretic example?

Comment: I updated my answer with a quick example on to set the value from a textbox to something which can then be reused for other things.

Comment: Thank you, but there is just one snag with this example. There should be two methods used here: one private void button1_Click, and one private void combobox1_selectedIndexChanged. The string combobox1 uses, can only be accessed after button1_click has successfully run.

Comment: once you have the value you then need to update the items of your dropdown. So you will write another method somethingl ike UpdateDropDownContent and change the dropdown as you need to. Finally the SelectedIndexChanged will then trigger with the updated values so again, you can do what you need. Does that make sense?

Comment: I know you have the best intentions, but no, I don't quite follow. You want me to create a third method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!
I was eventually able to do it like this, to truly access the variable inside the scope of method2, while it was created in method1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string output = "test";
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\output.txt", output)
        }
private void combobox1_SelectedItemChanged
        {
            string output = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\output.txt")
            // do something with this string
        }
    }
```